# If $m_1c_1 = m_2c_2$, how to solve it for the unknown $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

While solving some temperature questions as to physics, I had found an equation which I couldn't solve for $T$, where $T$ is the final temperature of water.

$$3m_1c_1(T-30)+m_2c_2(T-10)=0$$

If $m_1c_1 = m_2c_2$, how to solve it for the unknown $T$?

Let me show my attempt

$$3(T-30) + (T-10) = 0\implies3T - 90 +T -10 = 0$$

$$4T = 100 \implies T = \boxed{25}$$

Comment: That's correct so long as $m_1c_1\ne 0$

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you :)

Comment: To say however that the question is from linear algebra is a little exaggeration :)

Comment: @Widawensen Sorry for making that mistake!

Comment: @Liam Not very big "mistake", your equation is although linear, only 1-dimensional.

Comment: @Widawensen However, am still not sure whether or not that equation seems okay.

Comment: @Liam It's ok. Now you have the answer of pranavB23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are perfectly correct.

$3m_1c_1(T-30)+m_2c_2(T-10)=0$

$\implies T(3m_1c_1+m_2c_2)+(-90m_1c_1-10m_2c_2) =0$

$\implies T(4m_1c_1) +(-100m_1c_1) = 0$

$\implies T =\dfrac{100m_1c_1}{4m_1c_1}$

$\implies T = 25$